# Spring integration TCP client throwing 'Socket closed during message assembly' exception

Tags: spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In Kotlin/Java, When I try to send a bytearray message to a TCP server and receive the message, I am getting the exception

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception while awaiting reply; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Socket closed during message assembly
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:189)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:179)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46)
```

Below is my TCP configuration class

```
@Configuration
class TcpIntegrationConfiguration(
    private val tcpConfigurationProperties: TcpConfigurationProperties
) {

    @Bean
    fun tcpClient(): IntegrationFlow {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gateway::class.java)
            .handle(
                Tcp.outboundGateway(
                    Tcp.netClient(
                        tcpConfigurationProperties.host, tcpConfigurationProperties.port)
.soTimeout(tcpConfigurationProperties.timeout)))
.get()
    }
}
```

Any answers/suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You need to show the full stack trace (cause etc) as well as the server-side code.

But `Socket closed during message assembly` seems quite clear.

The server closed the socket without sending a complete reply; the default deserializer expects to see `\r\n` to signify the end of the message.

Comment: Got the answer from one of your earlier comments for another question. Setting the deserialiser to ByteArrayRawSerializer did the job. Thank you.